# Why the running time of a multiprocessing code is the same with diffierent number of cores?

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, slurm

I have something strange with my code. In fact I have a multiprocessing code.

So when i run this code with 1 cpu its takes around 218 min. With 32 cpus and 12 gb per cpu it takes around 35 minutes. And with 10 cpus and 12 gb it takes around 35 minutes. Noting that, my code loads two files which together have 10gb.

Can someone help by diagnostic how I can check why the running time is the same with 10 and 32 cores?

Normally, with 32 cpus it should take less time, no?

the code is running through a script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=def-hmcheick
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 32
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=12G
#SBATCH --time=02:00:00
module load python/3.5.4
source "/project/ENV3.5.4/bin/activate"

time mpirun python /project/myproject/executor.py
```

In executor.py I have a dictionary where each key has a list of values which I want to compare the key with each value in this list. How can I do that? in another words how can I pass the key and the the list of value to be be computed in parallel way. What I did is the following:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(32) as executor:
            for key, vector in executor.map(unwrap_self_alignment, zip([self]*len(keyList), keyList)):
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you are running. Anyways, one possibility is that your code does not scale well to the point that adding more CPUs can even be slower.

You could try to run your code with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32 CPUs and check the curve shape.

Comment: Are the 32 cores within the same NUMA domain? If not, then some NUMA effect (e.g. suboptimal data locality) can kill both performance and scaling. Also keep in mind OpenMP scaling is ruled by Amdahl’s law, and scaling up to 32 threads requires a virtually all your code is efficiently parallelized. You might experience more scalability by running more MPI tasks(1 per NUMA domain) and hence less OpenMP threads. Last but not least, if your app is memory-bound(and not cpu-bound) adding more threads will not improve performances.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, can you please give more details? Im sorry but im new to parallel way code design. How can i know if they are in the same NUMA?

Comment: You can run `lstopo` from the `hwloc` package in order to display the topology (that includes NUMA domains) of your machine.